# Get the name of the top most image with hover tool and show the tooltip at a fixed position

Tags: python, bokeh, python-3.8

I need to assign a name to each plot in the same figure. I want to get this name of the top most plot upon hovering or tapping in the figure. For now I use a `TextInput` to show the name. Inside the CustomJS, what is the correct method to access the name of the plot? I googled around and couldn't find a document for what is inside the `cb_obj` or `cb_data`. Thank you for any help.

[image]

Sample code:

```
from bokeh.server.server import Server
from bokeh.plotting import figure, ColumnDataSource, show
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models import Button, HoverTool, TapTool, TextInput, CustomJS

import numpy as np

def make_document(doc):

    p = figure(match_aspect=True)
    img1 = np.random.rand(9, 9)
    img2= np.random.rand(9, 9)
    p.image(image=[img1], x=0, y=0, 
            dw=img1.shape[0], dh=img1.shape[1], 
            palette="Greys256", name='image1')
    p.image(image=[img2], x=5.5, y=5.5, 
            dw=img2.shape[0], dh=img2.shape[1], 
            palette="Greys256", name='image2')

    text_hover = TextInput(title='', value='', disabled=True)
    callback_hover = CustomJS(args=dict(text_hover=text_hover), code="""
        text_hover.value = cb_obj['geometry']['name']; 
        """) # what should be used here?

    hover_tool = HoverTool(callback=callback_hover, tooltips=None)
    p.add_tools(hover_tool)

    doc.add_root(column([p, text_hover], sizing_mode='stretch_both'))

apps = {'/': make_document}
server = Server(apps)
server.start()
server.io_loop.add_callback(server.show, "/")
try:
    server.io_loop.start()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print('keyboard interruption')
print('Done')
```

I noticed there exists a [`tags`](https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/plotting.html?highlight=image_url#bokeh.plotting.figure.Figure.image_url) argument, it can be accessed in `CustomJS`, but how?

> tags (List ( Any )) –
>
> An optional list of arbitrary, user-supplied values to attach to this
> model.
>
> This data can be useful when querying the document to retrieve
> specific Bokeh models
>
> Or simply a convenient way to attach any necessary metadata to a model
> that can be accessed by CustomJS callbacks, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By consulting multiple sources, got a temporary solution:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, ColumnDataSource, show
from bokeh.models import HoverTool, CustomJS
import numpy as np

img1 = np.random.rand(9, 9)
img2= np.random.rand(9, 9)

source = ColumnDataSource(dict(image=[img1, img2],
            name=['image1', 'image2'],
            x=[0, 5.5],
            y=[0, 5.5],
            dw=[img1.shape[0],  img2.shape[0]],
            dh=[img1.shape[1],  img2.shape[0]]))

p = figure(match_aspect=True)
render =p.image(source=source, image='image', x='x', y='y', dw='dw', dh='dh', name='name', palette="Greys256")

callback = CustomJS(code="""
                    var tooltips = document.getElementsByClassName("bk-tooltip");
                    for (var i = 0, len = tooltips.length; i < len; i ++) {
                    tooltips[i].style.top = ""; // unset what bokeh.js sets
                    tooltips[i].style.left = "";
                    tooltips[i].style.top = "0vh";
                    tooltips[i].style.left = "4vh";
                    }
                    """)

hover = HoverTool(renderers=[render], callback=callback)
hover.tooltips = """
    <style>
        .bk-tooltip>div:not(:last-child) {display:none;}
    </style>
    @name
"""
p.add_tools(hover)
show(p)
```

Answer (score -1):

You just need to access `p.title.text`:

```py
from bokeh.io import show
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models import TextInput, CustomJS, HoverTool
from bokeh.plotting import figure

p = figure(title="Hello there")
p.circle(0, 0)

text_hover = TextInput(title='', value='', disabled=True)
callback_hover = CustomJS(args=dict(text_hover=text_hover, plot=p),
                          code="text_hover.value = plot.title.text;")

p.add_tools(HoverTool(callback=callback_hover, tooltips=None))

show(column([p, text_hover]))
```

Comment: Thanks, I have made it more clear. The figure contains multiple plots, each plot has its own name, which is not the ttitle of the entire figure.

Comment: You could use `name` or `tags` for this. Bokeh renders glyphs in the order they appear in `plot.renderers` so you will just have to sift through thre for the one you want.

Comment: @bigreddot, thanks. The problem is how to access `name` or `tags` in the code of `CustomJS`, is there any argument I need to pass to the `dict` of `CustomJS`? Or do I need to do a `for` loop over all the plots and see which plot is right under my cursor?

Comment: There is only one plot (with multiple renderers). Pass the plot in the `args` dict and then you can inspect `plot.renderers`.

Comment: @bigreddot, thanks. After inspection I can find the `name` of `image1` in `p['attributes']['renderers'][0]['attributes']['name']`. The issue now is how can I tell if the cursor is over `image1` or `image2`. Do I need to do a `for` loop to check which image encloses the coordinate of the cursor?

Comment: Use `p.renderers[0].name` instead. Users should never use `attributes` I can't really advise about the other, it sounds fairly plausible.